# AWS EKS Kubernetes and DockerHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a cluster and node creates in AWS EKS. I applied the deployment to that cluster as under

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

Where deployment.yaml contains the containers' specification along with DockerHub repo and image

However, I did a mistake in deployment.yaml and I need to re-apply it to the configuration

My question is:

1 - How do I reapply a deployment.yaml to the AWS EKS cluster using kubectl?
Just running the above command is not working (`kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`)

2- After I re-apply the deployment.yaml , will the node will go an pick up the DockerHub image or do I still need to do something else( supposing all the other details are ok)

Some outputs below:

```
>> kubectl get pods

my-app-786dc95d8f-b6w4h   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          9h
my-app-786dc95d8f-w8hkg   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          9h
```

```
kubectl describe pod my-app-786dc95d8f-b6w4h                                                                            
Name:         my-app-786dc95d8f-b6w4h
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-192-168-24-13.ec2.internal/192.168.24.13
Start Time:   Fri, 10 Jul 2020 12:54:38 -0400
Labels:       app=my-app
              pod-template-hash=786dc95d8f
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:       Pending
IP:           192.168.7.235
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.7.235
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/my-app-786dc95d8f
Containers:
  simple-node:
    Container ID:
    Image:          BAD_REPO/simple-node
    Image ID:
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-mwwvl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-mwwvl:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-mwwvl
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From                                    Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----                                    -------
  Normal   BackOff  17m (x2570 over 9h)    kubelet, ip-192-168-24-13.ec2.internal  Back-off pulling image "BAD_REPO/simple-node"
  Warning  Failed   2m48s (x2634 over 9h)  kubelet, ip-192-168-24-13.ec2.internal  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

BR

Comment: How does "kubectl get pods" show ? How does "kubectl describe pod <name-of-pod>" show ?

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI: Hi Abdennour: I just added the requested outputs to the question.

Comment: Just re-running `kubectl apply -f` should update the cluster state.  When you say it's not working, what actually happens?

Comment: @David Maze: Thanks for your response. Nothing happened at all. The cluster remained  in the same status than above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ImagePullBackOff` means that kubernetes is not able to pull the image.

Specially, the service account "default" is not able to pull the image.

To fix this issue, you need two checks:

- Check that you don't have typo in the image name and tag. And that image is available publically.
- If the Docker registry is private, make sure to create secret with dockerlogin type, and then patch the service account "default" by this secret.

Comment: Yes I fixed the issue with the new deployment.yaml . Just wanted to reapply it

Answer (score 6):

if you need to change image:

```
kubectl set image deployment.v1.apps/{your_deployment_name} image_name:tag
```

but you always can do

```
kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

since your image is in `ImagePullBackOff` - it doesn't work anyway and you can just recreate deployment. Usually you don't do drop/create on prod. that is why i am using image change all the time. just have to change tag on every new image.